# embedding/displaying a windows form in a Web form for a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, embed, windowsformsintegration

So I'm trying to integrate various windows forms into a Web form for a website that I've created for my project in visual studio (c#). the problem is, I'm failing. I've searched online and the results of the search have mostly told me that it's not really possible, or its too complicated to be worth it. I, unfortunately, don't have much of a choice because my project is due in a day and I won't have enough time to redo all my modules in Web forms. there are 3 modules, 2 of which are games in a windows form and one is a picture dictionary in a windows form. the website has a button that once you click it, the game is loaded and the user is allowed to play it whilst it is embedded in the website. Any help will be much appreciated as this is a very stressful time. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Briefly: it's impossible.

Comment: I agree with @AlexanderPetrov. You cannot paste/embed winforms into webforms (or any other type of website).